# SQL: Select a list of numbers from "nothing"

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql, sequence

What is a fast/readable way to SELECT a relation from "nothing"  that contains a list of numbers. I want to define which numbers by setting a start and end value. I am using Postgres SQL and SQLite, and would be interested in **generic** solutions that will work on both/many platforms.

Desired output relation:

```
# x
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

I know that I can SELECT a single row from "nothing": `SELECT 0,1,2,3,4` But this selects the values as columns instead of rows and requires to specify all values in the query instead of only using my start and end values: `0` and `4`.

In Postgres you have a special `generate_series` function for this case:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,4) x;
```

This works nicely but is non-standard. I can also imagine some complicated solutions using temporary tables, but I would like to have something generic AND simple like:

```
SELECT * FROM [0..4]
```

Maybe using the `SEQUENCE` statement or some magic combination of `SELECT 0` and `SELECT 4`?

Comment: You might as well use numbers up to 1,000 I'd say -- put an index on the table perhaps. Otherwise, create views such as numbers_to_1000, numbers_to_1000000 to encapsulate those crossjoins.

Comment: @Juve, could you accept some answer or post your answer and accept it?

Comment: When I started looking, I was astonished at how awkward this simple-seeming task is to achieve. Here's an article with some more possibilities (but it suggests that nothing tops GENERATE_SERIES() from PostgreSQL): https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/19/how-to-create-a-range-from-1-to-10-in-sql/

Comment: A lot of ideas aren't options for a read-only environment such as BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers!
Following the discussion I realized that using a [numbers table](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/The-integers-table) is not too complicated and works well and fast on both/many platforms:

```
CREATE TABLE integers (i integer);
INSERT INTO integers (i) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO integers (i) VALUES (1);
...
INSERT INTO integers (i) VALUES (9);
SELECT (hundreds.i * 100) + (tens.i * 10) + units.i AS x
FROM integers AS units
  CROSS JOIN integers AS tens
  CROSS JOIN integers AS hundreds
```

You just create this table once and can use it whenever you need a range of numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Well in SQL server (and PostgreSQL) I would use recursive common table expression: [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html)

```
with recursive Numbers as (
    select 0 as Number
    union all
    select Number + 1
    from Numbers
    where Number < 4
)
select Number
from Numbers
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1091)

But, as far as I know, there's no WITH in SQLite.

So, the possible solutions could be

- create a user defined function ([this](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3.html) could be helpful)
- create a table with numbers from 0 to max number you'll ever need, and then just select from it like this:

  ```
  select Number from Numbers where Number >= 0 and Number <= 4
  ```

Comment: The recursive CTE would work in Postgres as well (in fact it's the only "standard" way to do it - as nearly all modern DBMS support recursive CTEs nowadays)

Comment: true, I've just tried to help with SQLite, because he knows how to do it in PostgreSQL, but thank you, I'll edit the answer

Comment: While a recursive CTE would work in most modern DBMS, it has been proven as [a very inefficient way of generating a sequence](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2). I think the numbers table is by far the best approach.

Comment: @GarethD yes, in my production code I use numbers table for unknown ranges of numbers, dates

Comment: Thx, for the hint to the "numbers table", some further research then showed that you can cross join more ranges from this base table. (See my edit)

Comment: Recursive CTEs are soo much fun to write. Like puzzles. But they can be very slow to execute.

Comment: Also be warned that you cannot ONLY execute the `with .. as ()` clause without the following `select`. It will cause the error `
Incorrect syntax near ')'`

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do this in PostgreSQL and SQLite is as follows:

```
sqlite> select 1 union select 2 union select 3;
1
2
3
```

It should work in most RDBMS systems, but IIRC in Oracle you would have to use:

```
select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual union select 3 from dual;
```

But I don't have an Oracle DB to test it on.

Answer (score 2):

Some other alternative (tried in postgres, but should be working with others)

`select (0) as count union values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)`

Extending this sql with code will be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with MS SQL.  It's a bit of a cheat in that it requires the table you're querying to have at least as many rows as the quantity of numbers you want returned.  In my case I just wanted a list of five priorities that I could bind to a drop down list - but had to come from SQL given the way that other related UI elements worked:

```
SELECT WDPRIORITY, 
       CAST('Priority ' + LTRIM(STR(WDPRIORITY)) AS CHAR(16)) AS TXPRIORITY
  FROM (
         SELECT TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY WDVALUE ASC) AS WDPRIORITY
           FROM VMIPRS
       ) AS VMPRIORITY
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if somebody is looking for solution for MSSQL for known limited number of numbers:

```
SELECT x.x FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS x(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

If the number set is limited, I would go with:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (VALUES (1),(2), (3))
```