# MySQL: How do a i insert a specific number of blank rows into a table

Tags: mysql, loops, insert

I want to grab a variable (between 1-365) and use this value to create the number of empty rows in a table:

insert into tblCustomer (ID) values (), (), ();

is there an easier way to do this or is using a loop the best way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673549/sql-select-a-list-of-numbers-from-nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A procedure with an IN parameter is quite easy

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_loop(IN number INT)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT(11);

 SET x = 1;    

 WHILE x  <= number  DO
 INSERT INTO tblCustomer(id)  VALUES('');
 SET  x = x + 1; 
 END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How to use it

```
CALL test_loop(20);
```